# How do I use Vue Router when injecting Vue into the webpage via content-scripts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, browser-extension

Hi I’m using Vue 2 with the Vue plugin, [vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension](https://github.com/adambullmer/vue-cli-plugin-browser-extension). I’ve been able to configure the plugin so that I can inject Vue into a webpage via content-script.js (currently I’m not using an iframe to inject into, I just attach the vuejs app to a div in the website).

When I click on any of the router links, they try to prepend the website’s domain and navigate to a page on that site. Instead I would like the Vue route/page to load.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Should I be using an iFrame to inject the Vue app into, I’m not 100% sure how to do that though :)

Thanks

Comment: You can't use a router and not have the url changed. But you can obtain a route-like functionality with an alternative solution using either Vuex, Vue.observable or Event.bus. Totally doable. Basically you need a container and change its contents based on the value of a state property called... "page"? Or "route"?

Comment: Is the Vue.observable in Vue 2 or is that a Vue 3 function? Also, can you provide any links to examples of how this can be achieved? Thanks I appreciate your time.

Comment: It was added in [2.6](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable).

Comment: Thanks @tao I think you're right, I found this too, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components which is probably all I need :)

Comment: I also followed this tutorial as a guide too, https://reactgo.com/vue-tabs-tutorial